# system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception exception occur with random scenario

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

we have .net windows application which is running on surface by client.application sometime crashes and every time scenario is different but in event logs exception is same system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception was unhandled. i cannot reproduce this issue.
here is the stack trace:

```
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
   at SpectrumNZ.GUI.Modules.frmMainShell.Dispose(Boolean)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()
```

and here is event logs:

```
Faulting application name: SmartClient.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5bb5f8a9
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.3130.0, time stamp: 0x5b175f1a
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x0007ca5b
Faulting process id: 0x1cac
Faulting application start time: 0x01d47c695f8665dc
Faulting application path: {path}\SmartClient.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 42f6b2d5-0936-4033-a6eb-edff18e8d7fa
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

cannot understand what is the issue behind. after doing some search i have found that it might be network issue but i'm not sure. i have update question with code where occurs

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing )
            {
                FlushMemory();
                //--------------------------------------
                if (components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }               

            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }



[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr process, int minimumWorkingSetSize, int maximumWorkingSetSize);
        public static void FlushMemory()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
            {
                SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
            }
        }
```

Please help me to find the cause of this exception.
Thanks

Comment: can you show us the code where the exception is been thrown?  SO is for coding issues.

Comment: i have update question with code

Comment: if you comment out the `FlushMemory();` line does it work?

Comment: not sure because crashing does not occur with same scenario

Comment: I think GC causes the exception. Try comment P/Invoke call (SetProcessWorkingSetSize) and test for it.

Comment: + Why did you call `GC.Collect`?

Comment: @SlaneR (GC causes the exception) can you explain why it's causing?

Comment: @farrukhaziz I don't know much about GC so I can't tell you what is the exactly causing exception, but I found some document describe about it's reason. 
http://www.sysnet.pe.kr/Default.aspx?mode=2&sub=0&detail=1&pageno=0&wid=11307&rssMode=1&wtype=0

Comment: + it says "Caused by finalizer after GC performed, so it's unable to get call stack information"

Comment: That's might not be the best describe your situation, but I recommend you to NOT call GC in `Dispose` method. GC will automatically cleanup your "unused(not reachable = no one use/reference)" resources as well.

Comment: The error is STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR; see http://errorco.de/win32/ntstatus-h/status_in_page_error/0xc0000006/

Comment: I think the two last parameters in your P/Invoke declaration should be IntPtr instead of int?

Comment: @KlausGütter can you explain STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR error?

Comment: @KlausGütter I thought PInvokeStackImbalance occurred if P/Invoke signature is wrong, not SEHException.

Comment: STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR: see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081204-00/?p=19963